# AutoIt: does not click on the button of the embedded installer

Tags: automation, autoit

I am trying to click on the button(s) of the embedded installer (QuickTime) which pops up during a software installation, however, I've tried to use ControlClick, ControlSend, Send functions and it won't click on the button and proceed to the next page. I have also tried different ways to access the button IDs, but no luck... :(

However, I managed to get the handle of the pop up QuickTime window, and managed to use the handle to get the title of the QuickTime installation window. The result of clicking on the Next button also returned as 1 too, but from the GUI side, it wouldn't proceed to the next page. I can automate the first installer without any issues...

Source code:

```
$quickTimeHandle = WinWait($quicktimeInstallWindowTitle, "Welcome", 90000)
ConsoleWrite("$quickTimeHandle >>>" & $quickTimeHandle & @LF)
if $quickTimeHandle <> 0 Then
    $quickTimeNext = ControlClick($quickTimeHandle, "Welcome", $quicktimeNextButtonText)
    ConsoleWrite("$quickTimeNext >>>" & $quickTimeNext & @LF)
```

From the output:

```
$quickTimeHandle >>> 0x0004046A
$quickTimeNext >>> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for **#RequireAdmin** when dealing with external window manipulation.

Comment: No problem. You can select the answer if it was a solution for you. Regards